# Is there any way to read this file format into Python

Tags: python, file-format

Does this file **format** look like anything anyone has seen before (I trimmed a lot so you can see just the formatting):

```
<REAPER_PROJECT 0.1 "5.29/x64" 1493370961
  RIPPLE 0
  GROUPOVERRIDE 0 0 0
  AUTOXFADE 1
  ENVATTACH 1
  <TRACK {1157FED1-D15B-4B2B-A89E-BF3696E69030}
    NAME "Station VT"
    PEAKCOL 29129222
    <ITEM
      PLAYRATE 1 1 0 -1 0 0.0025
      CHANMODE 0
      GUID {2493C675-0CB3-433B-B8CD-D661290D7980}
      <SOURCE WAVE
        FILE "Audio\04-KTKE VT-glued-131121_1022 render 001.wav"
      >
    >
    <ITEM
      PLAYRATE 1 1 0 -1 0 0.0425
      CHANMODE 0
      GUID {2493C123-0C32-466B-B8CD-D66129123123}
      <SOURCE WAVE
        FILE "Audio\131343121_1022 render 001.wav"
      >
    >
  >
>
```

I've contacted the vendor of the program that generates this file to see if they could let me know how they generated the file, but I'm not sure if I'll get an answer back from them.  I'm guessing it's a structure of structures or something like that?  Kinda guessing as I'm not familiar with many other languages.

Ultimately I'd like to read this into Python, if possible, make some changes to the data, and then spit it back out to a file.  Otherwise I guess I'll just parse it line by line and make the changes that I need - not impossible, but would be much easier if there's already a reader that exists.

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned that I need to output the data in the same format as I read it in, so having a reader/writer would be ideal.

Comment: The people who own this file format are sure have re-invented the wheel, an ugly wheel. Ask them to use xml.

Comment: @swatchai hmm... I was wondering that.  It is close to XML,  but not quite.  I'm not sure why they went this route, but they did.  Unfortunately I doubt this format would be changing any time soon as it's a professional audio recording software that's used in a lot of studios and they probably wouldn't have much reason to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to XML, for instance:

```
def to_XML():
    with open('test/REAPER_in.txt') as f_in,\
         open('test/REAPER.xml', 'w') as f_out:

        tags = []
        while True:
            line = f_in.readline()[:-1].strip(' ')
            if not line: break

            if line.startswith('<'):
                eot = line.find(' ')
                if eot > -1:
                    tag = line[1:eot]
                    data = line[eot+1:].replace('"', '')
                    f_out.write( '<%s data="%s">\n' % (tag, data))


                else:
                    tag = line[1:]
                    f_out.write('<%s>\n' % (tag) )

                tags.append(tag)

            elif line.startswith('>'):
                tag = tags.pop()
                f_out.write('</%s>\n' % tag)

            else:
                eot = line.find(' ')
                tag = line[:eot]
                data = line[eot+1:].replace('"', '')
                f_out.write( '<%s>%s</%s>\n' % (tag, data, tag) )
```

> **Output**

```
<REAPER_PROJECT data="0.1 5.29/x64 1493370961">  
<RIPPLE>0</RIPPLE>  
<GROUPOVERRIDE>0 0 0</GROUPOVERRIDE>  
<AUTOXFADE>1</AUTOXFADE>  
<ENVATTACH>1</ENVATTACH>  
<TRACK data="{1157FED1-D15B-4B2B-A89E-BF3696E69030}">  
<NAME>Station VT</NAME>  
<PEAKCOL>29129222</PEAKCOL>  
<ITEM>  
<PLAYRATE>1 1 0 -1 0 0.0025</PLAYRATE>  
<CHANMODE>0</CHANMODE>  
<GUID>{2493C675-0CB3-433B-B8CD-D661290D7980}</GUID>  
<SOURCE data="WAVE">  
<FILE>Audio\04-KTKE VT-glued-131121_1022 render 001.wav</FILE>  
</SOURCE>  
</ITEM>  
</TRACK>
</REAPER_PROJECT>
```

Comment: So, the only problem with that is I still need to write the file back out in the original format... but that being said, it wouldn't really be that hard as I know the formatting.  Ultimately I was hoping someone might recognize the format, but it's looking like it's a custom format that the developer authored instead of using something standardized like XML.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear that I needed to output in the same format as well - I added an EDIT to more clearly state that.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: It's possible using `XML parser` to output in the same format. Depends if it's worth the effort.

Comment: I think having something that has error handling would be nice.  If I flip stuff around in the original text file, run the program (reaper), and open the file, it's still able to find the data and then when you save it reorders the elements.  So they've obviously written some kind of handler for that format - I was just curious if it looked like anything anyone's ever used - even from other languages?  I was wondering if it was just a tool that would dump some kind of complex data type and also read it in.

Comment: I see your point. The format is **very close** to `XML`. Adding a format `tag attribute` enforce to write it 100% as the original.